# Accessing wrong attribute when trying to reset value...?

Tags: python

In this example code I'm trying to make the whole pile of data callable:

```
class Data(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self._raw_data = data

        for key, val in data.items():
            if isinstance(val, dict):
                if 'data' in val.keys():
                    setattr(self, key, Dataset(val))
                else:
                    setattr(self, key, Data(val))
            else:
                setattr(self, key, val)

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return None

    @property
    def raw(self):
        return self._raw_data


class Dataset(Data):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self._raw_data = data
        super().__init__(data)
        for entry in self.data:
            # need to debug this
            self.data[self.data.index(entry)] = Data(entry)
```

What ends up happening is this. I'll try:

```
>>> example = {'dataset': {'id': 1, 'data': [{'param1': 3, 'param2': 4}, {'param1': 5, 'param2': 6}]}}
>>> data1 = Data(example)
>>> print(data1.dataset.id)
1
```

Now that works as expected. The problem the last line, which causes change in __raw_data attribute in Dataset object and I have no idea how (and also, looks wrong). Clearly I don't understand something important about inherritance. What I am trying to do is put all data into callable attributes, but also keep the raw data for all kinds of purposes. This is what I get however:

```
>>> print(data1.raw)
{'dataset': {'id': 1, 'data': [<wtf.Data object at 0x102a8da58, <wtf.Data object at 0x102a8da90>]}}
```

It should however return raw data as it was passed:

```
>>> print(data1.raw)
{'dataset': {'id': 1, 'data': [{'param1': 3, 'param2': 4}, {'param1': 5, 'param2': 6}]}}
```

It works for Data objects:

```
>>> for item in data1.dataset.data:
...     print(item.raw)
{'param2': 4, 'param1': 3}
{'param2': 6, 'param1': 5}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Indeed, I misunderstood your question. I also don't understand why you are accessing `self.data` in `Dataset`; why the assumption there is a `data` attribute? Also, on the `Dataset` setting `self.__raw_data` *again* is pointless when you don't access it anywhere in that subclass.

Comment: At any rate, you are modifying the list object at `self.data`. That is a reference to one of the lists  in the datastructure that `self.__raw_data` also references. They are not copies. See [this article](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) on how names and references work in Python.

Comment: The comment thread got deleted by my stupidity, I apologize. (tried to edit)
The explicit 'data' thing is just an example (Forecast.io API does this for its Data Block objects) if there isn't data attr, nothing happens, you get None if you try to call it. Indeed, setting _raw_data was pointless so thanks.

Comment: But why the loop over `self.data`? You do `for entry in self.data:` assuming that there *is* a `data` attribute on `self`. You then mutate that  list directly rather than create a new list object.